# Adding text inside of if() from a function

Tags: javascript

I am having a little problem, I made this function :

```
function arrayCounter(number){
    var textToReturn = "";
    for(var i =1; i<=number;i++){
        textToReturn += "array[i"+(+(i-1))+"] == arrayText["+(i-1)+"]";
        if(i != number){
            textToReturn = textToReturn + " && ";
        }
    }
    return textToReturn;
};
```

and I am using this function inside IF condition here :

```
for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(arrayCounter(arrayText.length)){
```

but it doesnt work, and If I manually added the result of arrayCounter() inside the IF condition it will work, what should I do to make it work ?

Comment: Probably need a combination of single and double quotes

Comment: What do you want it to do inside the `if()`? The function returns a string, so as long as it returns a non-empty string, the `if()` will be true.

Comment: Are you expecting this to `eval()` inside the `if()`?

Comment: I tested the result with console.log() and I copied it and pasted inside the IF condition and everything works great. but it does not work when I add the function inside the IF condition

Comment: @victory that's just not at all how JavaScript works ...

Comment: Tip: Let `i` run from `0` to `number-1`, then you can omit the `-1`.

Comment: @Pointy Thats how it works for me, I am not using it to design anything I am using it as a crawler with phantomJS Engine

Comment: @victory no, no, what I mean is that your expectations of how that works are just completely wrong. It would help a lot if you would describe what you are trying to achieve; what is the condition that you want to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but it doesnt work

It does work and return the text as you want.

> I am using this function inside IF condition here

…but an if-condition expects a boolean value, not a string! You were basically executing

```
if ("array[0] == arrayText[0] && array[1] == arrayText[1]") {
```

but needing

```
if (array[0] == arrayText[0] && array[1] == arrayText[1]) {
```

> what should I do to make it work ?

<sub><sup>You could `eval()` the string, but do not do that.</sup></sub> `eval` is bad practise, it should not be used for this.

Instead, create a `function arrayCondition` that you pass the two arrays and which does return a boolean!

Comment: I dont quite get you and I have no idea what is eval() can you please answer in code so I understand you better

Comment: @victory can you describe in words what it is that you want that function to do?  Is it trying to see if all the elements of the array are the same?

Comment: @Pointy I need the function to search for a text and print what is after the Text. Function will take 2 parameters (string to look for, and Break char) example : 

text : I am 25 years old
function('am ',' ')
output : 25

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure it actually will work even with an `eval()`; the constructed expression will involve references to non-existent variables "i0", "i1", etc.

Comment: @Bergi I understand now. but why is Eval() not a good practise

Comment: @Bergi you are brilliant, This looks more easy and clean. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, it is more clean :-)